# Google Appengine Standard Endpoints V2 with Auth0 security

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints, auth0, google-app-engine-python

I try using **google endpoints v2 in Python using Auth0 in standard appengine** but if i follow the documentation my endpoints are open for all public.
I have proved using the next options with the next result:

### 1ª option

In my endpoints class:

```
@endpoints.api(name='ganadero', version='v1',api_key_required=True,
                audiences={'auth0_jwk': ['ganadero-api.endpoints.XXXX.appspot.com','https://YYYYY.es','https://ZZZZZ.eu.auth0.com/api/v2/']},
                issuers={'auth0_jwk': endpoints.Issuer('https:// ZZZZZ.eu.auth0.com',
                                           'https:// ZZZZZ.eu.auth0.com/.well-known/jwks.json')}) class GanaderoAPI(remote.Service):
```

I compiled with the next command:

```
python lib/endpoints/endpointscfg.py get_openapi_spec main.GanaderoAPI --hostname ganadero-api.endpoints.XXXX.appspot.com
```

My ganaderoV1openapi.json is the next:

```
    "/ganadero/v1/ganadero/ususarios": {
      "get": {
        "operationId": "GanaderoAPI_obtenerExplotaciones",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "format": "int64",
            "in": "query",
            "name": "identificador",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "in": "query",
            "name": "nombre",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "in": "query",
            "name": "email",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "in": "query",
            "name": "metadatoEmail",
            "type": "string"
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "A successful response",
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/MainMensajeUsuario"
            }
          }
        },
        "security": [
          {
            "api_key": [],
            "auth0_jwk": []
          }
        ],
        "x-security": [
          {
            "auth0_jwk": {
              "audiences": [
                "ganadero-api.endpoints.XXXXX.appspot.com",
                "https://YYYYY.es",
                "https://ZZZZZ.eu.auth0.com/api/v2/"
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "produces": [
    "application/json"
  ],
  "schemes": [
    "http"
  ],
  "securityDefinitions": {
    "api_key": {
      "in": "query",
      "name": "key",
      "type": "apiKey"
    },
    "auth0_jwk": {
      "authorizationUrl": "",
      "flow": "implicit",
      "type": "oauth2",
      "x-google-issuer": "https://ZZZZZ.eu.auth0.com",
      "x-google-jwks_uri": "https://ZZZZZ.eu.auth0.com/.well-known/jwks.json"
    }
  },
  "swagger": "2.0"
}
```

Next, i use the next command:

```
gcloud service-management deploy ganaderov1openapi.json
Waiting for async operation operations/serviceConfigs.ganadero-api.endpoints.XXXXX.appspot.com:c1195c3a-9a3f-4c0d-86fa-21f40a8a647e to complete...
Operation finished successfully. The following command can describe the Operation details:
 gcloud service-management operations describe operations/serviceConfigs.ganadero-api.endpoints.XXXXX.appspot.com:c1195c3a-9a3f-4c0d-86fa-21f40a8a647e
Waiting for async operation operations/rollouts.ganadero-api.endpoints.XXXXX.appspot.com:2017-08-27r2 to complete...
Operation finished successfully. The following command can describe the Operation details:
 gcloud service-management operations describe operations/rollouts.ganadero-api.endpoints.XXXXX.appspot.com:2017-08-27r2

Service Configuration [2017-08-27r2] uploaded for service [ganadero-api.endpoints.XXXXX.appspot.com]

To manage your API, go to: https://console.cloud.google.com/endpoints/api/ganadero-api.endpoints.XXXXX.appspot.com/overview?project=ganadero-146707
```

Next, I use:

```
gcloud app deploy -v endpoint
```

Now, my endpoints is deploying. But the problem is that I have use the API-KEY in the URL always. In the documentation said that I can used “x-api-key” in the header, but not function. Also, I must use the access_token of Auth0 in the header the next form:

Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IlFqbEdNVVEzTkRCR09FUkJPRGxCUTBSR1JUZzJPVUl4UkRjeU0wRXpRVFUwTUVReVEwRkVSQSJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL3NlcmVuby5ldS5hdXRoMC5jb20vIiwic3ViIjoiWDdDR1dPbkpSczg4ZFdRbjV0eUZtdjVodk5BQ1d6TTNAY2xpZW50cyIsImF1ZCI6Imh0dHBzOi8vZ2FuYWRlcm8uZXMiLCJleHAiOjE1MDM4MzMzMjIsImlhdCI6MTUwMzc0NjkyMiwic2NvcGUiOiIifQ.k0rnc58YfLfAxjQJ7T22jViVAL0-CPqAmOTYSVKUtzDGTvmhrMqLXYYQb35nEsr3uGDfnkUL4O1g3pQkamdKIzz1gstcl_NaizchwtUfl0Wr60_MAP4PH1yyqb5aH7Jn6gBvJPb-aFDCulkHhCq9OjWg9-qLgyO4hd1_F-U4Jq3SMSDrCVyrsZcjJiwhgUmAWmqIuy_fiKCS3CJHF_rnTL3ZIYxfvzPasVzLPPM93vD5mZR8sEhuN1l0AHGprcp4gf0nuLHcMK8ZbYXvcmJyelbIRkGkrLZJFZTUlWKh-4N3nKoZDUVR4JFwTlOXCR8coTTa7JctxZNU9_NqeIeRfg

But is not necessary if I put &key= AIzasd0Z4t-8GasfasdfXDqrcKIki6CIog in the URL. If only add Authorization Bearer “access-token” in the header or add x-api-key “API-KEY” or add two options always appear the next error:

*

> 401 Method does not allow callers without established identity. Please
>   use an API key or other form of API consumer identity to call this
>   API.

*

Only function the next form:

https:// XXXX /_ah/api/ganadero/v1/ganadero/documentos?idExplotacion=5668600916475904&key= AIzaSyD0Z4t-V8as345bzLLz2XDqrcKIki6CIog

### 2ª option:

In my endpoints class:

```
@endpoints.api(name='ganadero', version='v1',
                audiences={'auth0_jwk': ['ganadero-api.endpoints.XXXX.appspot.com','https://YYYYY.es','https://ZZZZZ.eu.auth0.com/api/v2/']},
                issuers={'auth0_jwk': endpoints.Issuer('https:// ZZZZZ.eu.auth0.com',
                                           'https:// ZZZZZ.eu.auth0.com/.well-known/jwks.json')})
class GanaderoAPI(remote.Service):
```

I compiled with the next command:

```
python lib/endpoints/endpointscfg.py get_openapi_spec main.GanaderoAPI --hostname ganadero-api.endpoints. XXXX.appspot.com
```

My gaanderov1openapi.json is the next:

```
   "/ganadero/v1/ganadero/ususarios": {
      "get": {
        "operationId": "GanaderoAPI_obtenerExplotaciones",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "format": "int64",
            "in": "query",
            "name": "identificador",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "in": "query",
            "name": "nombre",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "in": "query",
            "name": "email",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "in": "query",
            "name": "metadatoEmail",
            "type": "string"
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "A successful response",
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/MainMensajeUsuario"
            }
          }
        },
        "security": [
          {
            "auth0_jwk": []
          }
        ],
        "x-security": [
          {
            "auth0_jwk": {
              "audiences": [
                "https://YYYYY.es",
                "https://ZZZZZ.eu.auth0.com/api/v2/"
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "produces": [
    "application/json"
  ],
  "schemes": [
    "http"
  ],
  "securityDefinitions": 
    "auth0_jwk": {
      "authorizationUrl": "",
      "flow": "implicit",
      "type": "oauth2",
      "x-google-issuer": "https://ZZZZZ.eu.auth0.com",
      "x-google-jwks_uri": "https://ZZZZZ.eu.auth0.com/.well-known/jwks.json"
    }
  },
  "swagger": "2.0"
}
```

Next, i use the next command:

```
gcloud service-management deploy ganaderov1openapi.json

Waiting for async operation operations/serviceConfigs.ganadero-api.endpoints.XXXXX.appspot.com:b669eef3-97a3-430a-aacc-4a721ebc0db2 to complete...
Operation finished successfully. The following command can describe the Operation details:
 gcloud service-management operations describe operations/serviceConfigs.ganadero-api.endpoints.XXXXX.appspot.com:b669eef3-97a3-430a-aacc-4a721ebc0db2
WARNING: ganaderov1openapi.json: Operation 'delete' in path '/ganadero/v1/ganadero/animal': Operation does not require an API key; callers may invoke the method without specifying an associated API-consuming project. To enable API key all the SecurityRequirement Objects (https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#security-requirement-object) inside security definition must reference at least one SecurityDefinition of type : 'apiKey'.
WARNING: ganaderov1openapi.json: Operation 'post' in path '/ganadero/v1/ganadero/animal': Operation does not require an API key; callers may invoke the method without specifying an associated API-consuming project. To enable API key all the SecurityRequirement Objects (https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#security-requirement-object) inside security definition must reference at least one SecurityDefinition of type : 'apiKey'.
WARNING: ganaderov1openapi.json: Operation 'put' in path '/ganadero/v1/ganadero/animal': Operation does not require an API key; callers may invoke the method without specifying an associated API-consuming project. To enable API key all the SecurityRequirement Objects (https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#security-requirement-object) inside security definition must reference at least one SecurityDefinition of type : 'apiKey'.
WARNING: ganaderov1openapi.json: Operation 'get' in path '/ganadero/v1/ganadero/animales': Operation does not require an API key; callers may invoke the method without specifying an associated API-consuming project. To enable API key all the SecurityRequirement Objects (https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#security-requirement-object) inside security definition must reference at least one SecurityDefinition of type : 'apiKey'.
WARNING: ganaderov1openapi.json: Operation 'get' in path '/ganadero/v1/ganadero/compraVenta': Operation does not require an API key; callers may invoke the method without specifying an associated API-consuming project. To enable API key all the SecurityRequirement Objects (https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#security-requirement-object) inside security definition must reference at least one SecurityDefinition of type : 'apiKey'.
WARNING: ganaderov1openapi.json: Operation 'post' in path '/ganadero/v1/ganadero/compraventa': Operation does not require an API key; callers may invoke the method without specifying an associated API-consuming project. To enable API key all the SecurityRequirement Objects (https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#security-requirement-object) inside security definition must reference at least one SecurityDefinition of type : 'apiKey'.
WARNING: ganaderov1openapi.json: Operation 'delete' in path '/ganadero/v1/ganadero/documento': Operation does not require an API key; callers may invoke the method without specifying an associated API-consuming project. To enable API key all the SecurityRequirement Objects (https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#security-requirement-object) inside security definition must reference at least one SecurityDefinition of type : 'apiKey'.
WARNING: ganaderov1openapi.json: Operation 'post' in path '/ganadero/v1/ganadero/documento': Operation does not require an API key; callers may invoke the method without specifying an associated API-consuming project. To enable API key all the SecurityRequirement Objects (https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#security-requirement-object) inside security definition must reference at least one SecurityDefinition of type : 'apiKey'.
WARNING: ganaderov1openapi.json: Operation 'get' in path '/ganadero/v1/ganadero/documentos': Operation does not require an API key; callers may invoke the method without specifying an associated API-consuming project. To enable API key all the SecurityRequirement Objects (https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#security-requirement-object) inside security definition must reference at least one SecurityDefinition of type : 'apiKey'.
WARNING: ganaderov1openapi.json: Operation 'post' in path '/ganadero/v1/ganadero/explotacion': Operation does not require an API key; callers may invoke the method without specifying an associated API-consuming project. To enable API key all the SecurityRequirement Objects (https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#security-requirement-object) inside security definition must reference at least one SecurityDefinition of type : 'apiKey'.
WARNING: ganaderov1openapi.json: Operation 'post' in path '/ganadero/v1/ganadero/usuario': Operation does not require an API key; callers may invoke the method without specifying an associated API-consuming project. To enable API key all the SecurityRequirement Objects (https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#security-requirement-object) inside security definition must reference at least one SecurityDefinition of type : 'apiKey'.
WARNING: ganaderov1openapi.json: Operation 'get' in path '/ganadero/v1/ganadero/ususarios': Operation does not require an API key; callers may invoke the method without specifying an associated API-consuming project. To enable API key all the SecurityRequirement Objects (https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#security-requirement-object) inside security definition must reference at least one SecurityDefinition of type : 'apiKey'.
Waiting for async operation operations/rollouts.ganadero-api.endpoints.XXXXX.appspot.com:2017-08-27r1 to complete...
Operation finished successfully. The following command can describe the Operation details:
 gcloud service-management operations describe operations/rollouts.ganadero-api.endpoints.XXXXX.appspot.com:2017-08-27r1

Service Configuration [2017-08-27r1] uploaded for service [ganadero-api.endpoints.XXXXX.appspot.com]

To manage your API, go to: https://console.cloud.google.com/endpoints/api/ganadero-api.endpoints.XXXXX.appspot.com/overview?project=ganadero-146707
```

Next, I use:

```
gcloud app deploy -v endpoint
```

Now, my endpoints is deploying and open for everybody. You can access them free. No security in them.

https:// XXXX /_ah/api/ganadero/v1/ganadero/documentos?idExplotacion=5668600916475904

### 3ª option:

In my endpoints class:

```
@endpoints.api(name='ganadero', version='v1',
                issuers={'auth0_jwk': endpoints.Issuer('https:// ZZZZZ.eu.auth0.com',
                                           'https:// ZZZZZ.eu.auth0.com/.well-known/jwks.json')})
class GanaderoAPI(remote.Service):
```

I compiled with the next command:

```
python lib/endpoints/endpointscfg.py get_openapi_spec main.GanaderoAPI --hostname ganadero-api.endpoints. XXXX.appspot.com
```

My openapi.json is the next:

```
    "/ganadero/v1/ganadero/ususarios": {
      "get": {
        "operationId": "GanaderoAPI_obtenerExplotaciones",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "format": "int64",
            "in": "query",
            "name": "identificador",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "in": "query",
            "name": "nombre",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "in": "query",
            "name": "email",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "in": "query",
            "name": "metadatoEmail",
            "type": "string"
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "A successful response",
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/MainMensajeUsuario"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "produces": [
    "application/json"
  ],
  "schemes": [
    "http"
  ],
  "securityDefinitions": {
    "auth0_jwk": {
      "authorizationUrl": "",
      "flow": "implicit",
      "type": "oauth2",
      "x-google-issuer": "https://ZZZZZ.eu.auth0.com",
      "x-google-jwks_uri": "https://ZZZZZ.eu.auth0.com/.well-known/jwks.json"
    }
  },
  "swagger": "2.0"
}
```

Next, i use the next command:

```
gcloud service-management deploy ganaderov1openapi.json
Waiting for async operation operations/serviceConfigs.ganadero-api.endpoints.XXXXX.appspot.com:66091d01-910d-485d-af58-1a68a2dd2321 to complete...
Operation finished successfully. The following command can describe the Operation details:
 gcloud service-management operations describe operations/serviceConfigs.ganadero-api.endpoints.XXXXX.appspot.com:66091d01-910d-485d-af58-1a68a2dd2321
WARNING: ganaderov1openapi.json: Operation 'delete' in path '/ganadero/v1/ganadero/animal': Operation does not require an API key; callers may invoke the method without specifying an associated API-consuming project. To enable API key all the SecurityRequirement Objects (https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#security-requirement-object) inside security definition must reference at least one SecurityDefinition of type : 'apiKey'.
WARNING: ganaderov1openapi.json: Operation 'post' in path '/ganadero/v1/ganadero/animal': Operation does not require an API key; callers may invoke the method without specifying an associated API-consuming project. To enable API key all the SecurityRequirement Objects (https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#security-requirement-object) inside security definition must reference at least one SecurityDefinition of type : 'apiKey'.
WARNING: ganaderov1openapi.json: Operation 'put' in path '/ganadero/v1/ganadero/animal': Operation does not require an API key; callers may invoke the method without specifying an associated API-consuming project. To enable API key all the SecurityRequirement Objects (https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#security-requirement-object) inside security definition must reference at least one SecurityDefinition of type : 'apiKey'.
WARNING: ganaderov1openapi.json: Operation 'get' in path '/ganadero/v1/ganadero/animales': Operation does not require an API key; callers may invoke the method without specifying an associated API-consuming project. To enable API key all the SecurityRequirement Objects (https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#security-requirement-object) inside security definition must reference at least one SecurityDefinition of type : 'apiKey'.
WARNING: ganaderov1openapi.json: Operation 'get' in path '/ganadero/v1/ganadero/compraVenta': Operation does not require an API key; callers may invoke the method without specifying an associated API-consuming project. To enable API key all the SecurityRequirement Objects (https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#security-requirement-object) inside security definition must reference at least one SecurityDefinition of type : 'apiKey'.
WARNING: ganaderov1openapi.json: Operation 'post' in path '/ganadero/v1/ganadero/compraventa': Operation does not require an API key; callers may invoke the method without specifying an associated API-consuming project. To enable API key all the SecurityRequirement Objects (https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#security-requirement-object) inside security definition must reference at least one SecurityDefinition of type : 'apiKey'.
WARNING: ganaderov1openapi.json: Operation 'delete' in path '/ganadero/v1/ganadero/documento': Operation does not require an API key; callers may invoke the method without specifying an associated API-consuming project. To enable API key all the SecurityRequirement Objects (https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#security-requirement-object) inside security definition must reference at least one SecurityDefinition of type : 'apiKey'.
WARNING: ganaderov1openapi.json: Operation 'post' in path '/ganadero/v1/ganadero/documento': Operation does not require an API key; callers may invoke the method without specifying an associated API-consuming project. To enable API key all the SecurityRequirement Objects (https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#security-requirement-object) inside security definition must reference at least one SecurityDefinition of type : 'apiKey'.
WARNING: ganaderov1openapi.json: Operation 'get' in path '/ganadero/v1/ganadero/documentos': Operation does not require an API key; callers may invoke the method without specifying an associated API-consuming project. To enable API key all the SecurityRequirement Objects (https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#security-requirement-object) inside security definition must reference at least one SecurityDefinition of type : 'apiKey'.
WARNING: ganaderov1openapi.json: Operation 'post' in path '/ganadero/v1/ganadero/explotacion': Operation does not require an API key; callers may invoke the method without specifying an associated API-consuming project. To enable API key all the SecurityRequirement Objects (https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#security-requirement-object) inside security definition must reference at least one SecurityDefinition of type : 'apiKey'.
WARNING: ganaderov1openapi.json: Operation 'post' in path '/ganadero/v1/ganadero/usuario': Operation does not require an API key; callers may invoke the method without specifying an associated API-consuming project. To enable API key all the SecurityRequirement Objects (https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#security-requirement-object) inside security definition must reference at least one SecurityDefinition of type : 'apiKey'.
WARNING: ganaderov1openapi.json: Operation 'get' in path '/ganadero/v1/ganadero/ususarios': Operation does not require an API key; callers may invoke the method without specifying an associated API-consuming project. To enable API key all the SecurityRequirement Objects (https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#security-requirement-object) inside security definition must reference at least one SecurityDefinition of type : 'apiKey'.
Waiting for async operation operations/rollouts.ganadero-api.endpoints.XXXXX.appspot.com:2017-08-27r3 to complete...
Operation finished successfully. The following command can describe the Operation details:
 gcloud service-management operations describe operations/rollouts.ganadero-api.endpoints.XXXXX.appspot.com:2017-08-27r3

Service Configuration [2017-08-27r3] uploaded for service [ganadero-api.endpoints.XXXXX.appspot.com]

To manage your API, go to: https://console.cloud.google.com/endpoints/api/ganadero-api.endpoints.XXXXX.appspot.com/overview?project=ganadero-146707
```

Next, I use:

```
gcloud app deploy -v endpoint
```

Now, my endpoints is deploying and open for everybody. You can access them free. No security in them.

https:// XXXX /_ah/api/ganadero/v1/ganadero/documentos?idExplotacion=5668600916475904

Answer (score 0):

Specifying audiences and issuers controls what kind of authorization the framework will consider valid. However, it does not by itself require that a valid authorization exists.

The [Endpoints framework docs](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/python/authenticating-users#authenticating_with_auth0) have three steps for Auth0; the third step is to check the result of `endpoints.get_current_user()` in every method where you want to enforce authentication.

This is not exactly ideal, but this is the way things are right now.